# Link button to another button

Tags: html, css

I don't really know how to explain it properly in English but I want to link a button to an action.

Example:

I have vertical tabs and when you select one of these tabs the relevant content is shown.

```
<div class="vertical-tabs">
<ul class="tabs vertical" data-tab="">  
    <li class="tab-title active"><a href="#panela1" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panelb1" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content">
    <div class="content active" id="panela1" aria-hidden="false" >
        <p>This is tab 1</p>
        <button>Tab2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="panelb1" aria-hidden="false" >
        <p>This is tab 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the `Tab1` content there is a button `Tab2`.

What I'm trying to achieve is when you click the `Tab2` button in the content section of `Tab1` then the action is the same as when you click `Tab2` in the `tabs vertical` section.

With pictures:
[image]

Now `Tab1` is active and you get the content linked to `Tab1`, but when you click the button `Tab2` in the content field of `Tab1` I want to go to the content of `Tab2`

[image]

Hope I've explained well enough what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Paulie_D. I've tried everything that I could find. with onclick etc but each time nothing happens.

Comment: replace `<button>` with `<a href=""`></a>` and you have a working solution, now just simply style the link in content like a button and you are done

Comment: @Wouter: What did you try?  How specifically did it fail?  We can help with that.  "I wrote this code, and on line X I'm expecting Y to happen, but Z happens instead.  Why?" is a question we can answer.  "I gave up, someone do this for me" is not.

Comment: One of the many solutions I've tried was the solution Dirk is proposing. But it doesn't work as nothing happens. I've also tried <button onclick="window.location.href='/panelb1'">Tab2</button>

Comment: Maybe I didn't say it but I've tried every solution I could find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn your buttons into labels and then use a radio to show the corresponding tab:

```css
.radio,
.content {
  display: none;
}

.radio:checked+.content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-tabs">
  <ul class="tabs vertical" data-tab="">
    <li class="tab-title active"><label for="panel1-radio">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab-title"><label for="panel2-radio">Tab 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabs-content">
    <input type="radio" name="show-panel" id="panel1-radio" class="radio" checked>
    <div class="content" id="panela1" aria-hidden="false">
      <p>This is tab 1</p>
      <label for="panel2-radio">Click to show Tab2</label>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="show-panel" id="panel2-radio" class="radio">
    <div class="content" id="panelb1" aria-hidden="false">
      <p>This is tab 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If you are wanting to highlight the tabs in the list, you are going to have to add a bit of js to add and remove classes bases on the selected checkbox

Comment: phew, it took me a while to fully understand your solution, but it works perfect! Thank you

Comment: @Pete how do I ask a follow up question? Everything works but I have some issues with the js and css

Comment: Ask a new question , post a snippet and then put a link in it to this question as context

Comment: @Pete I've made a follow up question with snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538760/call-content-with-button-js-issue